# Hide header component from App component

Tags: angular

I am trying to protect header component from login, forget password and reset password from app.component.html like bellow:

```
<app-header *ngIf="router.url != '/' && router.url != '/forget-password' 
&& router.url != '/reset-password/:email_for/:token_for'"></app-header>
```

Here `'/'` and `'/forget-password'` are working but `'/reset-password/:email_for/:token_for'` is not working. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the following (*If there is no other url with '/reset-password/' for which you want header* ):

```
<app-header *ngIf="router.url != '/' && router.url != '/forget-password' && router.url.indexOf('/reset-password/') == -1"></app-header>
```

Answer (score 4):

Better way to write a function that would check the condition and return a boolean from the ts,

```
isValid(): boolean {
  if ((this.router.url != '/') && (this.router.url != '/forget-password') && (this.router.url != '/reset-password/:email_for/:token_for')) {
            return true;
    }
  return false;
}
```

and call

```
<app-header *ngIf="isValid()"></app-header>
```

Comment: debug and see conditions are getting executed

Comment: It shows ERROR TypeError: _co.isValid is not a function

Comment: what is _co ? where does it come from?

Comment: Its coming from <app-header *ngIf="isValid()"></app-header>

Comment: Use '/reset-password/{{email_for}}/{{token_for}}'

Comment: Now there is no error but the problem is it does not prevent the header.

Comment: Yes I am sure because I can see the email address and the token

Comment: But you need to update the answer != does not work :)